# Send a buffer of uint16 data (288 values) over SPI from arduino to RPI (quickly)

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, spi

I have a device for taking spectrometer measurements. A raspberry Pi is used as a shell for a GUi and communicates over serial (USB) with an Arduino to read spectrometer values. The RPi sends a string to the Arduino to tell it to read the spectrometer. During each measurement all spectrometer pixel values (288) are stored to a uint16 buffer then sent back over serial to the Pi which waits for at least 3 seconds to read data from the Serial. right now it takes about 0.3 seconds for one measurement (including time for RPi to tell the Arduino to take a measurement, the time it takes to actually read the spectrometer, and then send all of the spectrometer values back over Serial to the Pi). I have tried to implement this using I2C but it wasn't much faster (I had to send each value byte by byte). I am trying to implement this with SPI (which will hopefully be faster but don't have any experience with this interface). Is there a simple way to tell the Arduino when to read then send a large buffer of data back to the Pi? (instead of sending it over piece by piece?)

(This is the most important part of my code, there is more to it but hopefully this gets the point across)

Arduino:

```
#define SPEC_CHANNELS    288 // New Spec Channel
uint16_t data[SPEC_CHANNELS];

void read_value()
{

  //Read from SPEC_VIDEO
  //analogReadResolution(16);
  for(int i = 0; i < SPEC_CHANNELS; i++){
      uint16_t readvalue = read_adc();
      data[i] = readvalue;

      // pulse the spectrometer clock to switch pixels
      digitalWriteFast(SPEC_CLK, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(delayTime);
      digitalWriteFast(SPEC_CLK, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(delayTime);

  }
  
// send the buffer info over serial (with some formatting) 
  for (int i = 0; i < SPEC_CHANNELS-1; i++){
    Serial.print(data[i]);
    Serial.print(',');
    
  }
  Serial.print(data[SPEC_CHANNELS - 1]);
  Serial.print("\n");
  
}
```

RPi:

```
self.ser.write(b"read\n")  #tell arduino to read spectrometer
data_read = self.ser.readline()   #read a full line of serial data 
data_temp = np.array([int(p) for p in data_read.split(b",")])  #parse the info by ","
```

Updated code:
Arduino:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
}
#define SPEC_CHANNELS    288 // New Spec Channel
uint8_t data[SPEC_CHANNELS*2];

void read_value()
{
for(int i = 0; i < SPEC_CHANNELS*2; i+=2){
      uint16_t readvalue = read_adc();
      data[i] = readvalue & 255;
      data[i+1] = (readvalue >> 8) & 255;
      digitalWriteFast(SPEC_CLK, HIGH);
      delay62ns(); 
      digitalWriteFast(SPEC_CLK, LOW);
      delay62ns();
  }
  Serial.write(data, SPEC_CHANNELS*2);
}

void delay62ns() {
  asm("nop");
}
```

RPi:

```
self.ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = 115200, timeout = 3)
self.ser.write(b"read\n")  #tell arduino to read spectrometer
data_read = self.ser.read(288*2)   #read a full line of serial data 
new_data = []
for x in range(0,288*2,2):
     new_data += [256*data_read[x] + data_read[x+1]]
data_plot = np.array(new)
print(data_plot)
```

output from the arduino Serial monitor:

```
g ⸮Og⸮⸮⸮ %⸮b⸮ ⸮'p⸮om⸮o ⸮⸮:p`ʏW⸮BOW⸮%�⸮ڊPX⸮z⸮b ⸮r⸮zB
b⸮⸮_⸮⸮ B⸮ ⸮ ⸮ ⸮R⸮rz⸮
7⸮⸮oxJϕ M0⸮% ⸮⸮ ⸮ /⸮ w⸮ ⸮ ⸮?U⸮W⸮%⸮ էW⸮⸮X⸮⸮⸮"⸮H ⸮⸮⸮R⸮⸮J⸮o7`z⸮ ⸮⸮*⸮5bB _⸮⸮Z⸮U U ⸮E⸮⸮⸮⸮ O⸮*⸮ ⸮2x*⸮b⸮o⸮z⸮}⸮_⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮
⸮⸮
=⸮:Ϛ⸮hW/�O-⸮`j⸮⸮
*⸮J⸮woB⸮⸮] ⸮⸮⸮w⸮⸮-⸮ (⸮ ⸮⸮⸮J:⸮eߗ_]⸮
```

output From Pi (with the working code above):

```
1586 1344, 1444, 1560 ...
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the baudrate? I would recommend timing your `read_value` function and use that as a point of reference. As for sending a large packet back to the RPi you could try something like the `ArduinoJson` library. The added bonus is that the json can be directly converted into a python object if needed such as a dictionary.

Comment: You could use `serial.write()` with `data` and `SPEC_CHANNELS*2` to send the whole buffer in a single write from the Arduino rather than converting to ASCII strings and doing 288 `serial.print()`. And obviously `serial.read()` on the RPi to match and `np.frombuffer()`.

Comment: @TeejayBruno I have the Highest BaudRate that the RPi will allow. It takes about 0.15 Seconds for the Read and write on the Arduino then the rest is on the RPi side

Comment: @MarkSetchell I will try this out Thank you!

Comment: I would expect the single write to be around 3x faster.

Comment: @MarkSetchell So i needed to convert the Uint16 values into two separate 8 bits. I have so far been unable to read on the Pi side  `data = self.ser.read(576)`. (When i look at the serial monitor it looks like gibberish which makes sense), but not sure why nothing is being seen on the Pi side

Comment: What is your `delayTime` please? If this is greater than the `serial.write()` time for 2 bytes, you may be able to *"hide"* your serial writes to the RPi behind your pixel switching when reading the spectrometer...

Comment: Maybe click `edit` under your question and add your latest/greatest code with a note saying what you are attempting and what actually happens in terms of results.

Comment: edited the post with updated code

Comment: Can you include your setup code for the serial interface at both ends too please?

Comment: Added a delay to the initialization of the serial and got some hex values on the Pi side (Im assuming just need to convert back to 16 bit integers and should be all set. I will test timing soon.

Comment: @MarkSetchell from the values i read from the Pi it seems that I get a lot of \t and random characters. I am unsure if my issue is with how i split up the 16 bit to 2 bytes or something else.

Comment: It's not going to make sense in the serial monitor - that is for ASCII data - but you are now sending binary data (not ASCII) so you need to do the `serial.read()` and then make a Numpy array from the data.

Comment: So that is the part I cannot figure out (may be outside the scope of this discussion) but my byte array that I read with the Pi has a bunch of random characters in it. It is not only  `b'x05\xc5\x08\xb0'` but looks something like `b'x05\t\R\xc5\x08\t\t\M\xb0'` Not sure what to make of that. Not sure how to split or parse that array correctly.

Comment: Make a Numpy array of `np.uint16` from it and print the Numpy array elements. For debugging, fill the `data` buffer with zeroes on the Arduino and send it. Then fill it with 128 and see what you get on the RPi, then fill it with 288 16-bit elements of 32768 and see what you get in the RPi.

Comment: If you do this `b'x05\t\R\xc5\x08\t\t\M'.hex(sep=' ')`, you can see that the bytes you received are `78 30 35 09 5c 52 c5 08 09 09 5c 4d` in hex.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I edited the code above and was able to read in normal values from the spectrometer. thank you for all of your help. It ended up going from about 0.3 sec to 0.16 sec for each read which is awesome! The actual write/read timing is about 22ms (150ms before). Do you think SPI would be any faster than this?

Comment: I have summarised some of our comments in an answer and added a simpler (hopefully faster) way of converting the bytes you read from serial into a Numpy array. I imagine SPI would be faster, but have not tried it... though I *may* wire up an Arduino and RasPi over the weekend to try it out... :-)

Comment: Not sure why you are building your `data` buffer on the Arduino side with assignments to `data[i]` and `data[i+1]` inside your `for` loop? If  `read_adc()` returns a `uint16` you can just put that straight into `data[i]` and move to the next value, surely?

Comment: As regards improving performance, you should measure exactly what is taking the time before you bother trying to optimise. So, you should measure the time to read the 288 samples from the ADC, and the time required to write them to the RasPi and also measure the time to re-assemble the data on the RasPi after reading it...

Comment: Could you indicate exactly which Arduino model and exactly which Raspberry Pi model you are using please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am using an Arduino Nano and  RPi 3B+

Comment: @MarkSetchell `Serial.Write()` will not allow me to send a buffer of type Uint16_t. Should i initialize `data` as a byte buffer even though What i am adding is a uint16_t value?

Comment: No, just cast it to `unsigned char *`

Comment: @MarkSetchell using an unsigned char * I get this in the output in the serial monitor `read)⸮ON5⸮OFF⸮set_inte{readpulsex⸮pulseП
X_@⸮5jWgJH⸮'⸮⸮zrRO/⸮⸮/z⸮O⸮]׊⸮⸮"⸮⸮or⸮⸮j%芇b⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮j⸮⸮B⸮EoH⸮5W⸮U⸮OW⸮ ⸮ read)⸮ON5⸮OFF⸮set_inte{readpulsex⸮pulse` Which seems to be reading variables from other functions within my script that use these strings to control other features in the program

Comment: You've got to forget the serial monitor. It only understands ASCII, which is really wasteful in performance terms. If you send a `uint16` in binary, that's 2 bytes, right? 16-bits. If that `uint16` is 10000, and you send it as ASCII for the benefit of the serial monitor, you need to send `1`, then `0`, then `0`, then `0`, then `0`, then `,` to separate it from the next reading. That's 7 bytes, right? Rather than 2? That means 3.5x slower.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I understand that. I misunderstood your last comment of casting as a unsigned char. I was initializing the buffer incorrectly so I was getting the wrong characters in my serial write (it wouldnt read on the RPi side). The serial monitor was just to show that how i initialized the buffer was giving weird results in the monitor which messed up the entire read process. I have it working now. The overall time decreased from ~0.3 second per reading (read and write) to ~0.1 sec which is plenty fast for my application. Thank you for all of your insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion in the comments was to send the data as binary rather than as ASCII strings, because if you imagine the 16-bit sample 10,000 it requires 2 bytes to be transmitted, whereas if you make it an ASCII string, it takes 6 bytes if you include the comma required to separate it from the next sample:

```
10000,
```

Glad to see it has improved the performance.

---

Another idea, if you want to maximise the reads per second, might be to continually read the spectrometer in anticipation of the Raspberry Pi asking for the data and then hand it over when asked. So, instead of:

```
do forever
    sit around idly wasting time till RPi asks for data
    read spectrometer
    send spectrometer readings to RPi
done
```

maybe do this:

```
do forever
    read spectrometer
    if there are serial bytes available (check in NON-BLOCKING way)
        send latest spectrometer readings (which we already have) to RPi
    end if
done
```

---

Another observation... though you mention delaying 62ns in your code (which corresponds to one cycle on a 16MHz clock), you should be aware that it potentially takes 4+ clock cycles to call your subroutine and 4+ further cycles to return so you are actually incurring 16+ cycles per reading more than you may expect. It doesn't amount to much in the great scheme of things, and your compiler may be inlining your function call anyway... but you get my drift, hopefully.

---

Imagine your Arduino gathers and sends 288 16-bit values from 0..287. You can synthesize the bytes buffer that you might receive on your `serial.read()` like this:

```
import numpy as np

buf = np.arange(288, dtype=np.uint16).tobytes()

 b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\x08\x00\t\x00\n\x00\x0b\x00\x0c\x00\r\x00\x0e\x00\x0f\x00\x10\x00\x11\x00\x12\x00\x13\x00\x14\x00\x15\x00\x16\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x19\x00\x1a\x00\x1b\x00\x1c\x00\x1d\x00\x1e\x00\x1f\x00 \x00!\x00"\x00#\x00$\x00%\x00&\x00\'\x00(\x00)\x00*\x00+\x00,\x00-\x00.\x00/\x000\x001\x002\x003\x004\x005\x006\x007\x008\x009\x00:\x00;\x00<\x00=\x00>\x00?\x00@\x00A\x00B\x00C\x00D\x00E\x00F\x00G\x00H\x00I\x00J\x00K\x00L\x00M\x00N\x00O\x00P\x00Q\x00R\x00S\x00T\x00U\x00V\x00W\x00X\x00Y\x00Z\x00[\x00\\\x00]\x00^\x00_\x00`\x00a\x00b\x00c\x00d\x00e\x00f\x00g\x00h\x00i\x00j\x00k\x00l\x00m\x00n\x00o\x00p\x00q\x00r\x00s\x00t\x00u\x00v\x00w\x00x\x00y\x00z\x00{\x00|\x00}\x00~\x00\x7f\x00\x80\x00\x81\x00\x82\x00\x83\x00\x84\x00\x85\x00\x86\x00\x87\x00\x88\x00\x89\x00\x8a\x00\x8b\x00\x8c\x00\x8d\x00\x8e\x00\x8f\x00\x90\x00\x91\x00\x92\x00\x93\x00\x94\x00\x95\x00\x96\x00\x97\x00\x98\x00\x99\x00\x9a\x00\x9b\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00\x9e\x00\x9f\x00\xa0\x00\xa1\x00\xa2\x00\xa3\x00\xa4\x00\xa5\x00\xa6\x00\xa7\x00\xa8\x00\xa9\x00\xaa\x00\xab\x00\xac\x00\xad\x00\xae\x00\xaf\x00\xb0\x00\xb1\x00\xb2\x00\xb3\x00\xb4\x00\xb5\x00\xb6\x00\xb7\x00\xb8\x00\xb9\x00\xba\x00\xbb\x00\xbc\x00\xbd\x00\xbe\x00\xbf\x00\xc0\x00\xc1\x00\xc2\x00\xc3\x00\xc4\x00\xc5\x00\xc6\x00\xc7\x00\xc8\x00\xc9\x00\xca\x00\xcb\x00\xcc\x00\xcd\x00\xce\x00\xcf\x00\xd0\x00\xd1\x00\xd2\x00\xd3\x00\xd4\x00\xd5\x00\xd6\x00\xd7\x00\xd8\x00\xd9\x00\xda\x00\xdb\x00\xdc\x00\xdd\x00\xde\x00\xdf\x00\xe0\x00\xe1\x00\xe2\x00\xe3\x00\xe4\x00\xe5\x00\xe6\x00\xe7\x00\xe8\x00\xe9\x00\xea\x00\xeb\x00\xec\x00\xed\x00\xee\x00\xef\x00\xf0\x00\xf1\x00\xf2\x00\xf3\x00\xf4\x00\xf5\x00\xf6\x00\xf7\x00\xf8\x00\xf9\x00\xfa\x00\xfb\x00\xfc\x00\xfd\x00\xfe\x00\xff\x00\x00\x01\x01\x01\x02\x01\x03\x01\x04\x01\x05\x01\x06\x01\x07\x01\x08\x01\t\x01\n\x01\x0b\x01\x0c\x01\r\x01\x0e\x01\x0f\x01\x10\x01\x11\x01\x12\x01\x13\x01\x14\x01\x15\x01\x16\x01\x17\x01\x18\x01\x19\x01\x1a\x01\x1b\x01\x1c\x01\x1d\x01\x1e\x01\x1f\x01'
```

Then to convert it to a Numpy array, all you need is:

```
data = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint16)
```

Depending on your byte ordering, you may need to set the `dtype` like this:

```
dt = np.dtype(np.uint16)
dt = dt.newbyteorder('>')                # You may need '<'
data = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=dt)
```

`data` now looks like this:

```
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
        26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
        39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,
        52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,
        65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,
        78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,
        91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103,
       104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,
       117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129,
       130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142,
       143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155,
       156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168,
       169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181,
       182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194,
       195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207,
       208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,
       221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233,
       234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246,
       247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259,
       260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272,
       273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285,
       286, 287], dtype=uint16)
```

On my machine, this is 140x faster than your code that builds a list.

**Keywords**: Python, serial, transfer, efficient, efficiency, performance, high performance, Raspberry Pi, Arduino, binary, ASCII, Numpy, ADC, spectrometer.